2000's romantic comedy about a family of men cursed to die at a specific age
I don't know anything of the movie, except that it is a 2000ish sorta romance film about a 20ish year old man that has a curse on his family where at a certain age all men die in accidents or the like. His mother and grandmother insist that he has a child before that happens, but he refuses and just wants to die. He falls in love with a woman (I think she was blonde) and that's all I know about the plot.
I remember a scene where his father dies by falling off a dock and it had something to do with an ice cream machine. Also I remember his mother meeting the girl and stating that "She has nice large hips" again related to the offspring issue. 

Sounds like Expiration Date from 2006:

Charlie Silvercould III carries around a family curse passed down from his grandfather; death by a milk truck on his 25th birthday. With eight days left, Charlie accepts his fate and starts taking care of his unfinished business, like watering his plants and returning his library books and so on. But while he's out casket hunting, he meets a girl who just won't let him die in peace.

As you can see in the trailer, his dad died when he was in a boat by the dock and a milk truck fell on him, and the girl Charlie falls in love with is blonde:




Oh my God! Walt, thank you so so much man, i've been looking for so long it was driving me mad. Thank you
